# Перехват POST WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#

Есть вопрос программно отсылаю GET запрос, после чего получаю страницу с HTML и JS (главное тут JS) его нужно исполнить в webbrowser'e после чего он отправляет пост запрос, вот в чем проблема как не дать POST запросу дойти до сайта т.е перехватить и записать его скажем в STRING переменную? Вариант просто вынуть JS и исполнить его скажем в jint не подходит так как код крайне запутан, самый простой вариант отдать его любому браузеру...

Comment: Раз вам известен код, то перед тем как вставить его в `WebBrowser` поменяйте путь для отправки на свой - решение в лоб

Comment: Да, такой вариант я рассматривал, но реализовать его в своем приложение было бы достаточно проблематично, я думал о создании какой либо прослойки для отлова POST запросов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перехвата запросов, идущих от C# WebBrowser, используйте [это](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/157329/http-monitor-for-webbrowser-control).

[(Ответ с англоязычного SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811587/intercepting-requests-made-by-webbrowser-in-c-sharp)